# Android Studio can't connect to AVD or real device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

My Android Studio version is 2.1.2 in Windows 10. there is no problem before, but today this occurred. And I can not debug my app.

How to solve ?

> emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 384MB
>   emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 384MB

And

> emulator: WARNING: ./android/metrics/metrics_reporter_toolbar.cpp:164: Can't upload usage metrics: Error

[Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZFcz.png)

[Event Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p71S9.png)

Comment: close your adb.exe from task manager..

Comment: i tried but it run again and nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. go to tools-->android-->avd manager
2. edit android virtual device and select show advanced settings
3. go to memory and storage and set VM heap 400MB
4. click finish and run avd

Comment: you can read about java heap size [here](http://www.azulsystems.com/content/how-java-garbage-collection-impacts-maximum-heap-size)

Answer (score 0):

Do you see any errors? Try to

```
adb kill-server
```

Comment: i have trid adb kill-server and adb start-server, but it didn' work

Comment: C:\Users\Alex>adb kill-server  

C:\Users\Alex>adb kill-server  
* server not running *  

C:\Users\Alex>adb start-server  
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *  
* daemon started successfully *

Answer (score 0):

Connect only one device through usb, close all the running emulators. Now run the project. It would show the device to run. Later start emulator and run the app, this time the emulator also would be shown to run the app.

This happened to me also, I have resolved in the above said way.

Comment: For now there is no problem, but I am afraid it will occur again.